# Unexpected results with npm fabric

Tags: javascript, browserify, fabricjs

I've got Browserify to bundle up jquery and fabric nicely into the build using npm versions of both - I can see them both and jquery seems to be working fine.  Fabric is being a bit weird though - requiring it seems to return a fabric object containing another fabric object.  I have a very basic module that does this:

```
var $ = require('jquery');
var fabric = require('fabric');


$(document).ready(function(){

    var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('fpCanvas');

});
```

But I just get

```
Uncaught TypeError: fabric.Canvas is not a constructor
```

However when I do

```
var $ = require('jquery');
var fabric = require('fabric');


$(document).ready(function(){

    var canvas = new fabric.fabric.Canvas('fpCanvas');

});
```

Everything works fine.  Am I requiring it the wrong way?  It's not a show-stopper as I can always call fabric.fabric throughout the application, but it's inelegant and a sign that something isn't quite right...

Answer (score 1):

You could always do this:

```
var fabric = require('fabric').fabric;

// ...

var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('fpCanvas');
```

Comment: Ugly, but less ugly than what I'm doing now :)